# How to use substr a column and fetch value between limits

Tags: sqlite

Let assume that there is a table as **`Sample`** and **`Name, Country, UnitID, HS`** column of type as text.

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    Name text,
    UnitID text,
    Country text, 
    HS text
)
INSERT INTO #TempTable 
    (Name, UnitID, Country, HS)
VALUES 
    ('User1',  'U1',  'US', 30),
    ('User2',  'U2',  'AS', 40),
    ('User3',  'U3',  'AS', 50),
    ('User4',  'U4',  'AS', 60),
    ('User5',  'U5',  'AS', 80),
    ('User6',  'U6',  'AS', 90),
    ('User7',  'U7',  'AS', 10),
    ('User8',  'U8',  'AS', 10),
    ('User9',  'U9',  'AS', 20),
    ('User10', 'U10', 'AS', 30),
    ('User11', 'U11', 'AS', 40),
    ('User12', 'U12', 'AS', 70)
```

Here, I need to update the HS value between U2 to U10.

So initially I tried to retrieve the value between 1 and 3.

```
select * from schedules where substr(unitIndex, 2, 1) between '1' AND '3'
```

But I received all the record instead of `U1 and U2 and U3` only.

Please correct me what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here.

You're trying to pull a field value apart.
Databases are generally quite *bad* at doing this.  They *love* putting things together, but dissecting them?  Not so much.

Secondly, you're trying to "interpret" a String value as a Number.
Notoriously easy to get the wrong result (for example, '2' > '12' whereas 2 < 12). 
Make sure that you convert the "numeric"[-looking] bit into a proper Number type that you can work with.

This should get you what you need.

```
select * 
from schedules 
where cast( substr(unitID, 2) as integer) between 2 and 10 ;
```